# Ruby character encoding issue with scraped HTML

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, nokogiri

I'm having a character encoding issue with a Ruby script that does some HTML scraping and parsing with the Nokogiri gem. At one point in the script, I call `join("\n")` on an array of strings that have been pulled from some HTML, which causes this error:

```
./script.rb:333:in `join': incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
```

In my logs, I can see `CafÃ©` showing up for some of the strings that would be included in the join operation.

Is it that some of the strings in my array to be joined are ASCII-8BIT and some are UTF-8 and ruby can't combine them? Do I need to convert or sanitize my strings after parsing them with Nokogiri (into UTF-8)?.

I tried `force_encoding('UTF-8')` and `encode('UTF-8')` on the scraped HTML content before I do anything else with it, but it didn't help. In fact, after I tried `encode('UTF-8')`, my script crashed even earlier when it called `to_s` on a string containing `CafÃ©`.

Character encoding always really confuses me. Is there something else I can do to sanitize the strings to avoid this error?

**Edit:**
I was doing something similar in Perl recently and used a module called `Text::Unidecode` and was able to pass my strings to a function that translates any problematic characters e.g. the letter `a` with an acute to the plain letter `a`. Is there anything similar for ruby? (This isn't necessarily what I'm aiming for though, if I can keep the a with acute then that's preferable I think.

**Edit2:**
<s>I'm really confused by this and it's proving difficult to reproduce reliably. Here's some code:</s>

```
[CODE REMOVED]
```

**Edit3:**
I removed the previously posted code example because it wasn't correct. But the bottom line is, whenever I try to print or call `to_s` on the string that was scraped, I get the encoding error.

**Edit4:**
It turned out in the end that the scraped html input was not what was causing the problem. I got the encoding error whenever I tried to print or call to_s on a hash containing, among other things, the scraped html text. The 'other things' were values from database queries, and they were being returned in `ASCII-8BIT`. To fix the issue, I explicitly had to call `force_encoding('UTF-8')` on each database value that I use (although I hear that the `mysql2` gem does this automatically so I should switch to that).

I hate character encoding.

Comment: According to the web page, the charset is UTF-8. I'm fetching/reading the page like `resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)` and `Nokogiri::HTML.parse(resp.body)`

Comment: Should I be indicating to one (or both) of these that I want to use a specific character encoding?

Comment: It isn't necessary, or even desirable, to keep saying "Edit...". We can see what you've edited if necessary. Instead, make sure that what you add makes sense in the flow of the question's text. Instead of trying explain what you're doing, give us the minimal code required to demonstrate the problem, along with the minimal sample input. Trying to explain doesn't do nearly as well as a few lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, `CafÃ©` is supposed to be `Café`. If we start out with `Café` in UTF-8 but treat the bytes as though they were encoded in ISO-8859-1 (AKA Latin-1) and then re-encode them as UTF-8, we get the `CafÃ©` that you're seeing; for example:

```
> s = 'Café'
 => "Café" 
> s.encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8> 
> s.force_encoding('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')
 => "CafÃ©"
```

So somewhere you're reading a UTF-8 string but treating it as Latin-1 and re-encoding it as UTF-8. I'd guess that Nokogiri is reading the page and thinking that it is Latin-1 or being told by your user agent that it is getting Latin-1 text. Perhaps you have a bad default encoding somewhere, or the HTTP headers are lying about the encoding, or the page itself is lying about its encoding.

You need to get everything into UTF-8 at the edges of your scraper. Figure out who is lying about the encoding and sort it out right there.

Don't feel bad, scraping and encoding is a nightmare of confusion, stupidity, guesswork, and hard liquor. Servers lie, pages lie, browsers lie, no one is happy.